# Xamarin form reflection error with windows

Tags: c#, reflection, xamarin, xamarin.forms

reading in the [official guide](https://developer.xamarin.com/api/member/System.Type.GetProperties()/) I tryed to use the reflection on a common file in a `Xamarin` form shared project.

My problems are with those rows:

```
this.GetType().GetProperties()
```

and

```
property.PropertyType.GetGenericTypeDefinition()
```

It always says that it is working on `xamarin.droid` - `xamarin.ios`, but never on `xamarin.windows` - `xamarin.winPhone`.

I took some of this code from a windows phone project (no xamarin) and it was perfectly working, why now I have this problem?

thanks

PS:
I'm using xamarin with Visual Studio 2015

Comment: Could you elaborate what is not working? Do you get any error messages?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The Reflection API has been [split up](https://visualstudiomagazine.com/articles/2012/11/29/typeinfo-reflection.aspx). You have to use `TypeInfo`.

```
using System.Reflection;
...
var properties = this.GetType().GetTypeInfo().DeclaredProperties;
var genericType = properties.First().PropertyType.GetGenericTypeDefinition();
```

If you would use a [PCL instead of a Shared library](https://docs.xamarin.com/guides/cross-platform/application_fundamentals/building_cross_platform_applications/sharing_code_options/), you would at least see that something is wrong, immediately. If you want to use your code across multiple platforms, you can only use the common subset of all their functions / classes. The PCL mechanism supports you finding this subset, because it doesn't allow classes / functions that are not part of this subset.